# Restrictions of Intellix APIs

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

The below documentation given for Sophos Intellix APIs does not mention the restrictions on file size or a number of submissions that can be made in a given time, are there any such restrictions in place or we can submit the file of any size and can we make any number of submissions in a given time:

https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/index.html

Comment: you must Contact the Sophos Support and the Question Doesn't belong here

Comment: The link says we can get development support on stack overflow using 'sophoslabs-intelix' tag, I want to know the limits in place so that I can put appropriate checks in my application. Why do you think otherwise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API docs says "The maximum size of the file is 4.5 MB (It will be increased in upcoming versions)."
The service is in Early Access Program (EAP) so do not expect so high performance.